# Python unicode encoding using UTF-8

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

I was following through python's [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode) on unicode and I've got a simple question to ask:
When I open up a python shell and type:

```
>>> unicode('\x80abc')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: ordinal
not in range(128)
```

I get the above error as expected since python attempts to convert the byte \x80 to unicode using the ascii encoding which can go as far as 127. (\x80 is 128).

However if I try again using th utf-8 encoding, I again get an error although somewhat different:

```
>>> unicode('\x80abc', 'utf8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid s
tart byte
```

What is going on here and how should I properly go about it?

Comment: what is the encoding in your console?

Comment: It's a Windows cmd using codepage 737.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `'\x80abc'` is a byte string (in Python < 3).  If you want to convert a byte string to a unicode string you have two options:  Either you *reinterpret* all bytes as single-byte unicode characters (you can simply prepend a `u` to the string literal then: `u'\x80abc'`) or you assume that the bytes string is a unicode string encoded using a particular codec (like ASCII, Latin1, UTF-8, etc.); then you would go as you attempted: by *decoding* it.

Calling `unicode()` is an explicit decoding.  And as Paulo pointed out, a `\80` is not valid in UTF-8, as it is invalid in ASCII.  You might try Latin1, though, this will work as it allows a `\x80` byte in its stream.

Comment: +1 I didn't want to upvote you because I liked that we had _the same reputation_ LOL but it is a good answer.

Comment: Let's see how long we can keep that _same_ reputation :-D

Answer (score 3):

It just happened that `\x80` is not a valid byte in UTF-8 either.

Take a look at [the charset for UTF-8](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/) and see that the *one byte* codes finish in `\x7f`.

If you want to prove your example, try with `latin1` and the `ñ` character: `unicode('\xf1abc','latin1')`. Without the encoding it will fail and with it it'll pass.